# Use iterator to call the non-static function in STL Set

Tags: c++, stl, set

In the following program, I have a class `A` with a non-static function `void add()`. I want use the iterator to call `add()` for each element in the set, but there is a error at the last element.

How can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    A(int x) { a = x; }
    void add() {a = a + 1; }
    bool operator<(A x) const { return a < x.a; }
};

int main()
{
    //type of the collection
    typedef set<A> IntSet;

    //define a IntSet type collection
    IntSet col1;
    IntSet::iterator pos;

    //insert some elements in arbitrary order
    col1.insert(A(3));
    col1.insert(A(4));
    col1.insert(A(5));

    //iterator over the collection and print all elements

    for(pos = col1.begin(); pos != col1.end(); ++pos)
    {
        (*pos).add();
        // ERROR!: Member function 'add' not viable:
        // 'this' argument has type'const value_type' 
        // (aka 'const A'), but function is not marked const
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: In a `std::set` you are **not allowed** to change the contents (it would mess up the ordering). `*pos` is giving you a `const A`, hence you can't call the non-`const` function `add()` on it. If you want to be able to change the stored `A`s you need to use a different container.

Comment: You cannot modify set<> and thus all set iterators are constant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632079/why-does-stdset-insert-return-a-non-const-iterator-and-yet-i-cannot-modify

Comment: `col1.insert(*new A(5));` causes a memory leak, the syntax you were looking for is `col1.insert(A(5));`, i.e. "calling" the classname to create an instance of it.

Answer (score 4):

Items contained in a `set<>` container are considered `const` and cannot be modified.  If they did, their identity might change but `set<>` wouldn't be aware of this, wreaking havoc on its internal structure as an item would be stored in a bucket where it didn't belong!

Consider, for example, that `set<>` uses your custom `operator<` overload in order to sort its contents.  What would you expect to happen if you change the `a` member variable while the object is contained in a set?  The set won't know that `a` changed and will leave the object where it was.

To fix this potential problem, `set<>` only gives you references to `const` instances of contained objects.

You will only be able to use `const` members of your class in this context, and `add()` is not declared `const`.  If you want to modify the object and have those changes reflected in the set, you will have to make a copy of the object, remove the original object from the set, make the change to your copy, and then add the copy to the set.