# Remove value at index of std::set<vector<string>>::iterator

Tags: c++11, vector, stl, set

Update—this question may be related ([Use iterator to call the non-static function in STL Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976149/use-iterator-to-call-the-non-static-function-in-stl-set))

I am creating a program that scans and parses a text file, creates a database, and evaluates queries based on schemes and facts.  My data structure is as follows:

```
Relation
    Scheme
    set<Tuple>
```

Where `Scheme` and `Tuple` inherit from `std::vector<std::string>`.  The `Scheme` and every `Tuple` should have the same number of elements, and I repeatedly need to remove the values at a certain index in all three.  For example, if I have:

```
Scheme
    C D H
Tuples
    EE200 F 10AM
    EE200 M 10AM
    EE200 W 1PM
```

organized so:

```
  C='EE200' D='F' H='10AM'
  C='EE200' D='M' H='10AM'
  C='EE200' D='W' H='1PM'
```

After removal at index 0 of every vector I should have:

```
  D='F' H='10AM'
  D='M' H='10AM'
  D='W' H='1PM'
```

I have written [this code](http://cpp.sh/2fbm) to localize the problem with an example.  I first erase the index in the `Scheme` (which is essentially a vector of strings) and then loop through every `Tuple` in the set and attempt to remove the value at the index.  In my example I forwent creating classes and instead just used `std::string` or `std::vector<std::string>`.  The problem is here:

```
    for(set<vector<string>>::iterator t = tempTuples.begin(); t != tempTuples.end(); ++t)
    {
        // how do I erase the element at t?  
    }
```

Where `tempTuples` is the set of `Tuple` objects (here just vectors of strings).  `(*t).erase((*t).begin())` gives an error (`no matching member function for call to 'erase'`) when inserted at this point.  How do I remove the value at an index here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error, you can see that the problem is that you have a `const_iterator`. This is because `set` automatically returns `const` iterators, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217878/c-stl-set-update-is-tedious-i-cant-change-an-element-in-place).

Comment: Okay, so can I fix it by making and modifying a copy and replacing the original element all in my `for` loop?

Comment: That would get rid of the error, but copying the vector twice every time you want to remove something seems a bit excessive. Maybe you should try some other data representation.

Comment: I thought so too, but I'm required to use `std::set` for this project.  However, the vectors I'll be copying will be pretty short (only 2–5 strings each) so I'm not that worried about performance in this case.